# ffmpeg drawboxを複数描画したい

Tags: ffmpeg

drawboxを使用して動画内に線を表示しておりますが、
こちら複数の線をいろいろなタイミングで描画したいと考えております。

```
 -i input -vf drawbox=10:10:1:200:color='#ff0000':8:enable='between(t,3,5)' drawbox=50:50:1:200:color='#ffff00':8:enable='between(t,10,13)' output
```

イメージとしては上記のコードのようにしたいのですが、
どうすれば複数の線を描画できますでしょうか

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

複数のdrawboxを指定する場合は`,`で区切る必要があります。

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "drawbox=10:10:1:200:color='#ff0000':8:enable='between(t,3,5)' , drawbox=50:50:1:200:color='#ffff00':8:enable='between(t,10,13)'" output.mp4
```

bashで実行してみました。bashが`'`を解釈するのを防ぐため、-vfオプションの値を`"`で囲んでいます。